# Failed showing data from controller into view laravel

Tags: laravel

I am using laravel 5.5, and i want to display my data from databases to view.

Here is the code of my controller

```
public function SUisAlatRusak()
    {
        $fixasetId = 1516;
        $nama_aset = FixAset::where('id_fixasset', $fixasetId)->first();
        $aset = AsetBergerak::where('id_fixasset', $fixasetId)->get();
        foreach($aset as $asets){
            $pengecekan = Pengecekan::where('id_aset_bergerak', $asets->id_aset_bergerak)->get();
            foreach($pengecekan as $cek){
                $item = PengecekanHasItem::where('id_pengecekan', $cek->id_pengecekan)->get();
            }
        }

        $data = (object) ([
            'nama_aset' => $nama_aset->assetname,
            'kode_aset' => $nama_aset->assetcode,
            'tanggal' => $cek->waktu_cek,
            'items' => (object) $item
        ]);
        // return dd($data);
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('SOPControl.Monitoring.pdfKerusakanAlat', compact('data'))->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');
        return $pdf->stream('Laporan_Kerusakan_'.Carbon::now().'.pdf');
}
```

And i want to show it in the table below

```
<table width="100%" border='1' cellpadding='3' cellspacing='2' style='BORDER-COLLAPSE:collapse;' borderColor='#000000'>
            <thead>
                <tr bgcolor="#eee">
                    <td width="2%">No.</td>
                    <td width="30%">Nama Item</td>
                    <td width="55%">Keterangan</td>
                    <td width="13%">Tanggal</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    @php $i=1;@endphp
                    @foreach ($data as $konten)
                    <td>{{$konten->nama_aset}}</td>
                    @endforeach
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

But it showing an error message

```
Trying to get property 'nama_aset' of non-object
```

Can anybody help me? Thanks for helping.

Comment: I don't think you should be looping `$data`. You'd access it by `$data->nama_aset`

Comment: I do looping $data because i want to display all the data from $data->items. It show no error message when i call the $data->nama_aset. But when i trying to display data from $data->items,there's error message.

Comment: If you want to loop over items, then you need to do `@foreach($data->items AS $item)`. If you're looping over `$data` `@foreach($data AS $konten)`, each iteration `$konten` going to be one of the keys, so `nama_aset` on the 1st, `kode_aset` on the 2nd, ...

Comment: Okay sir, i'll try this suggest for now.

Comment: It works on my code sir, it returns no error anymore.

Comment: Excellent. I'll adjust the comments to an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is when looping `$data`, the only time `$konten` will be an object is on the last iteration, when `$kontent` is `$data->items`:

```php
@foreach ($data as $konten)
<td>{{$konten->nama_aset}}</td>
@endforeach
```

In actually, this loop isn't required, as `$data` isn't an array of arrays, so you can access the properties of `$data` directly:

```
<td>{{ $data->nama_aset }}</td>
<td>{{ $data->kode_aset }}</td>
...
```

If you need to iterate over `items`, a simple `foreach` on `$data->items` is all you need.

```
@foreach($data->items AS $item)
...
@endforeach
```